# How do I share a VBA excel function within a team

Tags: excel, vba

I've written my first VBA Excel function, ConvertFromUSD(amount,currencyname,year), which uses an excel spreadsheet to look up an exchange rate from US Dollars to a specified currency for a specified year, and returns the converted sum.
It seems to work fine, and I've made it into an Add-in that I can use whenever I start a new spreadsheet or edit an existing one.
Now I want to make this add-in available to a couple of dozen other people in my team, but I can't see how to do it; should I send the .xla to each of them and get them to install it (if so, how?), or can I put it somewhere where their excel applications will automagically find it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can save it to a shared drive that each person can access and have them load it into Excel from there. That is easiest to update and maintain.. Or they can save it to a local drive on their machine and load it into excel from there, but you'll have to re-distrubite each time changes are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they just double click the `.xla` file it should work for them. It will probably disappear as soon as they close excel though.

The quick way to get it to stick around:

1. [enable their "Developer"
   tab](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php)
2. Navigate to the Developer tab
3. Click "Add-ins"
4. "Browse" to the .xla file
5. Ensure that it's "Checked" in the list

There is a folder where they will be displayed in the "Add-in" dialog automatically without browsing, but it depends on the version of excel. 2010, for instance, is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library`.

Comment: I'd add that when it comes up with the message box **Copy '...xla' to the Addins folder** if you click `No` then the xla will stay on the network and everyone uses the same file - much easier if you need to update the file at a later date.